# Is it possible to execute an ongoing job

Tags: kotlin

I have a Job like below

```
job = GlobalScope.launch {
    delay(5000)
    runOnUiThread {
        some unwanted code
    }
}
```

This job will wait for 5 seconds to execute. And to cancel it before 5 seconds I'm calling

```
job?.cancel()
```

Now, Is there a way to execute this job before 5 seconds have reached ?

I'm looking for something like `job?.forceExecute.ignoreDelays` or `job?.forceExecute.ignoreDelay("FirstDelay")` if there is a option for name like `delay(5000,"FirstDelay")`

That would be so helpful for me to avoid boiler plate code.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to execute the job, even if the job is cancelled ?

Comment: @OyaCanli No, based on condition I need to cancel or execute the job. Within 5 seconds.

Comment: So you want to skip the delay according to your condition? May be you don't need a delay but rather a timeout?

Comment: @OyaCanli my job has almost 100 lines of code. So, I need to make it's content as a function now which is time consuming. So, I'm asking is it possible to skip that delay part and execute the job before 5 seconds. If it's not possible I need to go with old java style of coding.

Comment: @OyaCanli I'm looking for something like `job?.forceEcecute.ignoreDelays`

Comment: There is DelayController class but I guess it is available only in tests: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-delay-controller/index.html

Comment: Otherwise, you can restructure your code. You don't have to put the delay there. Just to be sure if I understood correctly, you want to check for a condition which takes some time, according to condition you execute some task right away or don't execute it/cancel it. In case you have no infromation within 5 seconds, you want to execute the task anyways. Is it correct? (I try to understand why you put a delay there)

Comment: @OyaCanli You are right, Exactly that's what i'm trying to do. And I didn't understood the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution I can think of is to use **withTimeout** instead of delay and for executing the task in case of time out, you can check for TimeoutCancellationException

```
GlobalScope.launch {
        try {
            withTimeout(5000){
                //Imagine checkThisCondition() is a suspension function which will check the condition you need and return boolean
                val condition : Boolean = checkThisCondition()
                if(condition){
                    executeTheTask()
                }
            }
        } catch (e : TimeoutCancellationException){
            executeTheTask()
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is old and best Java way to achieve what I want. I'm using this code thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to execute this job before 5 seconds have reached ?

#### Answer

using nested `job` + coroutine `cancellation`

#### Try this

```kotlin
job = GlobalScope.launch {
    delayJob = GlobalScope.launch { delay(5000) }
        delayJob.join()

        runOnUiThread {
        some unwanted code
    }
}

// if you want ignore delay
delayJob.cancel()
```

Comment: great idea, but nesting co-routines like this ! is it a good way ? cause I always avoid nesting things.